# Android - How to get the selected item value from a spinner and put it into a string?

Tags: android, spinner

i read many similar questions on this thread, but none of them help me...
This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.imc_spinner);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.imc_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using

    imc_met = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

}
```

I declare imc_met as `public String imc_met;`. The problem is that imc_met does not contain the value of the selected item of the spinner, but it's null...

Where's the problem?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use:

> imc_met=Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Instead:

> imc_met = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

**Updated:**

Seem you assigning Listener to your spinner not in correct way, do something like below:

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                String imc_met=spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: If i put it into OnItemSeelected i give me the error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSelectedItem() from the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter>"

Comment: Sure, simply i declare it in this way: "public String imc_met;"

Comment: cleaned and refreshed but nothing change

Comment: @RobinHood: i added the code into onCreate method, but it always tell me the error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSelectedItem() from the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter>" on the row "imc_met=Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();"

Comment: At the end it seems to work.I added your code into OnCreate method, i used "imc_met = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();", and then i added these two methods in the public class:  
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
   long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub }
I have to check the code in order to understand how it works, but now it give me no error and the value of imc_met is correct.

Comment: can you please have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748389/appcompatspinners-entries-not-opening-timepickerdialog-on-selecting-it-second-t

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
imc_met=Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I'm sorry. I forgot

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        imc_met=Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I try but it tells me: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSelectedItem() from the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter>"

Comment: It gives me the same erroe putting it after "spinner.setAdapter(adapter);" and by deleting onItemSelected method

Comment: Need of `onItemSelected` if spinner value change then it won't return update one because you are suggesting him to do within `onCreate`.

Comment: If i delete the onItemSelected method it tells me "The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)" on the row of "public class MainActivity"

Comment: if i put it into onCreate method it tells me: "The type new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>)"

Comment: Already added, but it tells me "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSelectedItem() from the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter>"

Answer (score 2):

is

```
imc_met=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

not

```
imc_met=Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int position = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_value_array)).indexOf(address.getCountry());
```

This will get index by the value.

Answer (score 0):

If spinner isn't define in onCreate() method then have to use this:

```
String spinner_value = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1)).getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code in your `onCreate()` method:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```