# eclipse spinner item ids

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i'm trying to make a temperature converter app for an android.
i want to use 2 spinners ("From" and "To").
with 3 items, Celsius, Kelvin and Fahrenheit.
i also added one text field in which user will put a number in.
at the bottom there is a button "Convert" and one textview for a result.
now what i need is, to make when "Convert" button is pressed textview is replaced by result but depending on selected items in 2 spinners.
for example if selected items are from celsius to fahrenheit it should calculate result like this:
9/5*(number written by user)+32
so my question is how do i do that, i think i should use "if" but i'm not sure how, since items aren't defined by anything :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="From">
        <item>Celsius</item>
        <item>Kelvin</item>
        <item>Fahrenheit</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

btw this is xml file in values which i made for spinner obviously.
and here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.usc.uscconverter;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Spinner sp, sp2;
    TextView textFrom, textTo, textDegree, textResult;
    EditText editText1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ar= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.From, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sp.setAdapter(ar);

        sp2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ar2= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.To, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ar2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sp2.setAdapter(ar2);

        Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
        buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
i edited my main activity and added this:

```
 Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
        buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (sp.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Celsius") && sp2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Fahrenheit")){
                    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    num = editText1.getText().toString();
                    int d = 9/5;
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(num);
                    int r = d * n + 32;
                    textResult.setText(String.valueOf(r));
                }

            }


        });
```

no errors though, but when i launch the app it crashes, and in logcat it says like this:

```
11-29 18:42:24.890: D/dalvikvm(846): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-29 18:42:36.830: I/Choreographer(846): Skipped 165 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-29 18:42:37.840: D/gralloc_goldfish(846): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-29 18:42:41.740: D/dalvikvm(846): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 113K, 6% free 2971K/3156K, paused 39ms, total 46ms
11-29 18:42:41.980: I/Choreographer(846): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-29 18:42:43.240: I/Choreographer(846): Skipped 118 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-29 18:42:44.190: I/Choreographer(846): Skipped 102 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-29 18:42:45.330: I/Choreographer(846): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-29 18:42:45.630: I/Choreographer(846): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-29 18:42:50.050: D/AndroidRuntime(846): Shutting down VM
11-29 18:42:50.050: W/dalvikvm(846): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a42ba8)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846): Process: com.usc.uscconverter, PID: 846
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.usc.uscconverter.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-29 18:42:50.060: E/AndroidRuntime(846):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 18:42:54.150: I/Process(846): Sending signal. PID: 846 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545741/android-how-to-get-the-selected-item-value-from-a-spinner-and-put-it-into-a-st

Comment: still doesn't work, i'm not very experienced though, i've made a few apps but i never worked with spinners

Comment: And where is reference to the TextView textResult?

Comment: http://www.igreklik.com/slike/viewer.php?file=81823041550411233057.png&file_imgur=ujXpdQ4.png

and if you're gonna need anything else here is the whole thing:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/s8gwcjpssv9wcnb/USCConverter.rar

Comment: added textResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult); 
above editText1 = ...
but the result isn't right, i entered 20 celsius and it should be 68 fahrenheits, but it's saying that it's 52

Comment: int d = 9/5; <-- this is wrong 9/5 is 1.8 and it is not integer, try double :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your code:

```
textResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);
```

Comment: now it works, but the result is wrong, i enter 20 celsius for example and it should be 68 fahrenheit, but it's showing 52 instead.
i'd say it didn't calculate 9/5, just 20+32

Comment: int d = 9/5; <-- this is wrong 9/5 is 1.8 and it is not integer, try double :)