# Getting null object reference on TextView even when correct reference has been given

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, spinner

I have an `AppCompatSpinner` and I'm trying to set a text on a `TextView` here.

Here's my code:

```
eSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                final TextView eSpinnerTV = (TextView) adapterView.getSelectedView();

                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        mHourEnd = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        mMinuteEnd = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(activityName.this,
                                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                          int minute) {

                                        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                                        date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                                        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                                        date.set(Calendar.AM_PM, date.get(Calendar.AM_PM));

                                        sEnd(hourOfDay, minute);

                                        uTimeInSF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date.getTime());

                                        eString = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(date.getTime());

                                        // error on the line below
                                        eSpinnerTV.setText(uTimeAMPM);

                                    }
                                }, mHourEnd, mMinuteEnd, false);
                        timePickerDialog.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Here's `sEnd.java` file's code:

```
public void sEnd(int hour, int min) {
        if (hour == 0) {
            hour += 12;
            format = "AM";
        } else if (hour == 12) {
            format = "PM";
        } else if (hour > 12) {
            hour -= 12;
            format = "PM";
        } else {
            format = "AM";
        }

        uTimeAMPM = hour + ":" + min + " " + format;

    }
```

Here's the `xml` code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
       android:id="@+id/pTime"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:entries="@array/pTimeList"
       style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
</android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

Here's `pTimeList`:

```
<string-array name="pTimeList">
    <item>Pick a time..</item>
</string-array>
```

As soon as I'm clicking the `OK` button after choosing time from `TimePickerDialog`, the app is crashing giving this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` on the line specified in the code above.

What is causing this error even when this textview has been clearly reference above in the code as `final TextView eSpinnerTV = (TextView) adapterView.getSelectedView();`?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

```
eSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                **final TextView eSpinnerTV = (TextView) adapterView.getChildAt(position)**

                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        mHourEnd = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        mMinuteEnd = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(activityName.this,
                                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                          int minute) {

                                        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
                                        date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                                        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                                        date.set(Calendar.AM_PM, date.get(Calendar.AM_PM));

                                        sEnd(hourOfDay, minute);

                                        uTimeInSF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date.getTime());

                                        eString = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(date.getTime());

                                        // error on the line below
                                        eSpinnerTV.setText(uTimeAMPM);

                                    }
                                }, mHourEnd, mMinuteEnd, false);
                        timePickerDialog.show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: this worked. Have a similar issue. Please have look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40748389/6144372

Comment: same problem is there .???

Comment: nope... it is a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `adapterView`, use `view` object  second parameter of `onItemSelected` to get selected row View from Spinner:

```
final TextView eSpinnerTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

Comment: this is a `spinner`. the textview here is not something in the `xml` file but the text that appears as the selection.

Comment: @HammadNasir: Which object you are passing to setAdapter method ?

Comment: @HammadNasir: Ok which layout id passing when creating Object of `ArrayAdapter` ?

Comment: there is no `ArrayAdapter`. see the edited question please.

Comment: @HammadNasir: Use `android.R.id.text1` bez by default layout for Spinner is `simple_list_item_1`

Comment: Why down-vote please comment.

Comment: your comment worked, please edit your answer. Thanks!

Comment: help with this too... some similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40748389/6144372